# Remove X-Socket-Id from axios get request

Tags: axios

I get a CORS error and most likely is from X-Socket-Id. I tried to remove X-Socket-Id from Request Headers, but is not working..

> .... has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-socket-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
   .get(this.$URL + "/search/", {
      params: {
        q: this.search,
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(this.$KEY+ ":"),
      },
      transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
        delete headers.common["X-Socket-Id"];
        return data;
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution. Create axios with default settings, and for my specific case I had to remove X-Requested-With.

X-Sockets-Id, was already removed in my request.

```
  var instance = axios.create();

  delete instance.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];

  instance
    .get(this.$URL+ "/search/", {
      params: {
        q: this.search_for_company,
      },

      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(this.$KEY+ ":"),
      },
    })
```